# Why isn't explicit type casting for Math.pow() causing integer overflow?

Tags: java

I understand that the result of **Math.pow()** is a *double*.

However, why isn't the below code causing an integer overflow when I have explicitly casted the result to an int? 
Also, why is the result of both 'a' and 'b' the same i.e 2147483647

```
int a=(int)(Math.pow(2,377));
int b=(int)(Math.pow(2,32));
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: Because by casting you're explicitly renouncing any overflow check.

Comment: [How does double to int cast work in Java](//stackoverflow.com/a/12515017)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca    byte b= (byte)(120+10); System.out.println(b); I do not think that overflow check is renounced here, as the result here is -126,

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I thought you were asking why it doesn't throw an exception or something like that. Anyway yes, you're renouncing an overflow check. In your `byte` example an overflow *does* happen, as you noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a double is larger than the maximal int value, converting it to int will give you the maximal int value.